# String elimination with exception?

Tags: android, regex, string

```
String first = "books(32/400)";
String second = first.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

Result is `second = 32400`. That's OK.

But, I want to this result:

`second = 400`

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to achieve and what exactly is wrong?

Comment: you want to convert `try (32/400)` into `try (400)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have fixed structure with slash and bracket try tis

```
var result=first.substring(first.lastIndexOf("/")+1,first.lastIndexOf(")"));

result=400
```

Comment: Thank you all of you. This code OK for me. Of course for java :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex, you can tweak the pattern to exclude what you do not need.

```
        Regex regEx = new Regex(@"[books()]");
        string output = Regex.Replace(regEx.Replace(@"books(32/400)", ""), @"\s+", "");
        string result = output.Split('/').Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it with:

```
String second = first.substring(first.indexOf("/") + 1, first.indexOf(")"));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this pattern : **"`\\d+`"**

```
String first = "books(32/400)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(first);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```